# Using FUSE With A Parititon

Tags: filesystems, device-driver, mount, disk, fuse

I've implemented a (very) basic filesystem using FUSE.  As of right now, the way FUSE mounts the system is with:

```
./myfusesystem /path/to/mountpoint
```

This is all well and good, and creates the proper layer over the mountpoint.  But I'm not attempting to build a virtual filesystem; I'm working on an on-disk filesystem where data will be stored to a disk partition.  Thus, I want to use my FUSE filesystem with an actual device partition, something like:

```
./myfusesystem /dev/sdd2 /path/to/mountpoint
```

...where the data will be stored persistently on that partition.  Is this something that can be done with FUSE?  If so, how?  I cannot find any references to this in the documentation or the tutorials I've read.

Answer (score 0):

FUSE lets you store the data anywhere, but if you want to use the partition as a storage, it's your job to read/and write the data from/to it.